# How to create a stage with a filter on json file?

Tags: json, filter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, stage

I struggle to use a stage because one of the `json` file has syntax problems.

Do someone knows if it is possible to create a stage with a filter on file names with a `regex`?

I succeded doing so once the stage is created with :

```
list @my_stage pattern = 'mypattern'
```

But it seems I cannot integrate this constraint directly into the creation of the stage...

Answer (score 0):

A pattern cannot be specified when creating a stage, but operations performed over the stage can apply a pattern, which can help ignore your known bad files.

Patterns on stage files can be applied when [listing a stage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/list.html#syntax), [querying a stage directly](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html#query-syntax-and-parameters), and when performing [`COPY INTO <TABLE> FROM <STAGE>` commands](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#loading-using-pattern-matching).

The `COPY INTO <TABLE>` options also permit passing an [`ON_ERROR='CONTINUE'` option](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#copy-options-copyoptions) to automatically ignore unreadable rows in any file being loaded.